# Cordova - JQuery Mobile icons low resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

I am developing an application in cordova but when I run it on android or browser the icons really are low res. I found on the internet that I had to add this in the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

But with no result..

here is an fiddle which shows the problem: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/3ky97ggu/1/)

This is how I do the icons in code:

```
<i class="ui-icon-departure ui-btn-icon-notext inlineIcon"></i>
```

and the css:

```
.ui-icon-departure:after {
    background-image: url("../img/icons/vertrek-icon.png");
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: 18px 18px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe change your density? target-densitydpi=medium-dpi

Comment: @Eric all ready set the density to medium-dpi and also tried device-dpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with meta tags. You're using CSS to resize a 427x325 PNG to 18x18 - not only shrinking it to a fraction of its original size, but stretching it in the process.

Try saving a PNG with double its display resolution for a clear retina look (i.e. if it'll be 18x18 on the page, save it as 36x36).

Comment: I did saved it as 36x36 and set the background-size: 18px 18px but now it doesn't fit the boundaries. look at this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ky97ggu/2/

Comment: First, could you upvote & mark my answer as having solved your original problem? Second, I'm not sure I'm seeing the issue you're talking about with the image not fitting the boundaries - it looks quite good to me. Can you elaborate on what's wrong?

Comment: I can't see that issue occurring in the CodePen, but I believe I see the problem here: `.ui-icon-arrival { background: url("../img/icons/aankomst-icon.png") no-repeat !important; }`. By putting "!important" on the shorthand for background, you're overriding all other background properties including `background-size` for `.ui-icon-arrival`. You need to refactor your code so "!important" is on a more specific property like `background-image`.